# Modifying TV setting universally via PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, tv, display-settings

I was thinking of developing a program for Windows that can change TV settings. Where I work, we change TV settings often and on MANY tv's and I was wondering if it would be possible to enter data into a computer program (that I develop) and have it transferred to a TV via a cable (or wireless?). So that settings like brightness, etc could be changed straight from the computer that'll speed things up.

There's a lot of different TV brands, and I was wondering if this was universal or brand-specific?

I've got experience with c# and some java

Kind Regards,
Erik

Comment: What you want does not exist.  There is not universal standard.

Answer (score 3):

Although completely doable, it would be hard to do right.  Different manufacturers have different IR codes.  IR codes also vary from the same manufacturer in different models.

Take Logitech's Harmony universal remote controls as an example.  They keep a database of most of the common brands and models, but it is far from complete.  They rely on the end user to upload their configurations for data.

But, if you only have a handful of TVs and change basic settings, you can capture the IR codes with an IR receiver to do what you want.

Google [IR code databases](https://www.google.com/search?q=ir%20code%20database&oq=ir%20code%20d&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.2720j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) to get some preexisting databases out there.

Edit:  You can get an IR blaster to send the data to TVs like a remote.